Chart js. How to customize font styling for elements in the "Labels" array?
I am making a Gantt style chart that contains two labels in the Y axis, however I am hoping to find a way to make the "title" label be in bold, while the "description" is not. I've seen it asked elsewhere but haven't been able to find a solution that works for me. Additionally, does anyone know if its possible the render the "description" to the right of the main label, in essentially a "second y-axis label"? I am hoping to use QuickChart and ChartJs 2 for this but can modify if needed. Any insight is greatly appreciated!
{
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: [['Project'], ['Title 1', 'Description'], ['Title 2', 'Description'], ['Title 3', 'Description'], ['Title 4', 'Description'], ['Title 5', 'Description']],
    datasets: [{
      data: [
        [new Date('2024-06-02'), new Date('2024-07-07')],
        [new Date('2024-06-02'), new Date('2024-06-06')],
        [new Date('2024-06-04'), new Date('2024-06-10')],
        [new Date('2024-06-05'), new Date('2024-06-21')],
        [new Date('2024-06-10'), new Date('2024-06-16')],
        [new Date('2024-06-17'), new Date('2024-07-07')],
      ],
      backgroundColor: ['#60879e', '#89c0e0', '#89c0e0', '#89c0e0', '#89c0e0', '#89c0e0'],
    }, ],
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Gantt Example',
    },

    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        position: 'top',
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'week'
        },
        gridLines: {
          lineWidth: 0.,
          zeroLineWidth: 0,
          zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.3)',
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.3)',
        },
        ticks: {
          min: new Date('2024-06-01'),
          max: new Date('2024-07-07'),
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          lineWidth: 0.,
          zeroLineWidth: 0,
        },
      }],
    },
  },
}

I have tried various solutions such as modifying the pointLabel but it isn't working for me.
